# How can i find sum of subtraction in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, time-series

I would like to use a numpy function in a daily report, because my data is quite large.

Let consider i have a numpy 2d-array

```
A = array([[0, 1, 2],
          [1, 2, 3],
          [2, 3, 4],
          [3, 4, 5],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [5, 6, 7],
          [6, 7, 8],
          [7, 8, 9]])
```

I want to do something like this

```
abs(array([0, 1, 2]) - array([[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], ..., [7, 8, 9]])).sum()
abs(array([1, 2, 3]) - array([[4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], ..., [7, 8, 9]])).sum()
...
abs(array([3, 4, 5]) - array([[0, 1, 2], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]])).sum()
abs(array([4, 5, 6]) - array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]])).sum()
...
abs(array([7, 8, 9]) - array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], ..., [4, 5, 6]])).sum()
```

I have tried this, but cannot skip arrays with any of elements on the left side that are in array on the right side.

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    temp = np.roll(A, -i, axis=0)
    print(abs(temp[0] - temp[3:]).sum())
```

This is the expected results

```
results = [75, 54, ..., 30, 30, ...75]
```

Sorry for my poor english explanation, thank you.

Comment: @Phanwit Suriya post expected result

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi thank you, i've added the expected results. i want to do something like sum(abs(A[i] - A[select A where any element of A[i] not in A[:]]))

Comment: @CarsonArucard they are matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to have a simple one-liner solution involving only NumPy functionality, I propose this:

```
import numpy as np

results = np.apply_along_axis(arr=A, 
                              axis=1, 
                              func1d=lambda x: 
                               np.abs(x - A[~np.isin(A, x).any(axis=1),:]).sum()
                              )
```

The results is as expected:

```
array([75, 54, 36, 30, 30, 36, 54, 75])
```

Comment: is it possible to index the ```x``` in lambda function. i want to do like A[i:j] - A[mask] and try using it with multiprocessing to improve the speed.

Comment: Everything is possible. Instead of the `apply_along_axis` function, you can just iterate `for i in range(A.shape[0])` and replace each `x` with `A[i,:]`. Then you can choose which `i` goes into which thread or something similar. Usually when I have a big dataset and complicated operation I turn to Spark instead :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

=^..^=

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
          [1, 2, 3],
          [2, 3, 4],
          [3, 4, 5],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [5, 6, 7],
          [6, 7, 8],
          [7, 8, 9]])

def sum_data(select_row):
    # roll data
    rolled_data = np.roll(A, -select_row, axis=0)
    drop_numbers = []
    for item in rolled_data[0]:
        drop_numbers.append(item)

    # find rows to drop
    drop_rows = []
    for item in drop_numbers:
        # get rows
        gg = np.unique(np.where(rolled_data == item)[0])
        for number in gg:
            drop_rows.append(number)

    # get unique rows numbers
    unique_rows = list(set(drop_rows))
    del unique_rows[0]  # delete first number that is selected row

    # delete rows
    rolled_data = np.delete(rolled_data, unique_rows, axis=0)

    # calculate
    difference_value = 0
    for i in range(1, len(rolled_data), 1):
        difference_value += abs(rolled_data[0] - rolled_data[i]).sum()

    return difference_value

# loop over each row
collect_values = []
for j in range(len(A)):
    collect_values.append(sum_data(j))
```

Output:

```
[75, 54, 36, 30, 30, 36, 54, 75]
```